# What is std::ios::exceptions expected behavior in destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this snippet:

```
// Case 1: Explicitly calling close() does throw, as expected.
{
    std::ifstream f;
    f.exceptions ( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
    f.close();  // This will throw std::ifstream::failure, as close() on unopened file sets the failbit
}

// Case 2: close() will be called by destructor of object 'g', but does not throw.
{
    std::ifstream g;
    g.exceptions ( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
} // Does not throw, even though "g's" destructor will call close() method
```

Now I do understand that destructors should never leak exceptions in C++ (and that is perhaps the reason for the observed behavior in Case 2). My question is: Is the above observed behavior guaranteed to be so by C++ standards, or is it just an artifact (and if yes, is there any difference between C++03 & C++11 in this regard ? Any relevant citation to C++ standards will be very helpful).

Also, how is this special case of not throwing inside destructor usually implemented, does the destructor code simply catches exceptions thrown by close(), and ignores them ? Can someone point me to the implementation of this in any of the major compiler source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `virtual ~basic_filebuf();`
>
> **27.9.1.2/5** Effects: Destroys an object of class
>   `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>`. Calls `close()`. If an exception occurs
>   during the destruction of the object, including the call to close(),
>   the exception is **caught but not rethrown** (see 17.6.5.12).

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how does g++ implements it, because looking at the source code of header file fstream (g++ 4.6), this is what I see: `virtual ~basic_filebuf() { this->close(); }` .Don't see any try { } catch { } logic there :-/ - any clues ?

Comment: Ref (for gcc 4.9): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/libstdc++/api/a01201_source.html#l00219

Comment: Note that `exceptions()` method sits on `std::ios`, not on `streambuf`. `filebuf::close()` doesn't set `failbit` (it doesn't have a member in which to set it), and doesn't (normally) throw exceptions. It simply does nothing and returns `NULL` when there's no open file. In turn, `fstream::close` calls `filebuf::close` and, when the latter returns `NULL`, sets `failbit` (which may throw). However, `fstream`'s destructor does not call `fstream::close()` (it calls `filebuf::close` indirectly, via `filebuf` destructor).

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you observed is standard. The `basic_ifstream` class contains a `basic_filebuf` object (*§27.9.1.6*). The destructor of the `basic_filebuf` object calls `basic_filebuf::close` but suppresses any exceptions that are thrown.

Quoting *§27.9.1.2/5 [filebuf.cons]* (emphasis added)

> `virtual ~basic_filebuf();`
> *Effects:* Destroys an object of class
>   `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>`. Calls `close()`. If an exception occurs
>   during the destruction of the object, including the call to `close()`,
>   **the exception is caught but not rethrown** (see 17.6.5.12).